# Проблема с /f строками

Tags: python, users

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имя юзера - fishk. В строке, где есть путь к какому-нибудь файлу из пользователя, начало имени превращается в /f строку. Не хочу менять имя юзера, есть какой-нибудь другой вариант?

Comment: Экранируйте слэш `\\f`

Comment: Лучше используйте raw-string для путей файлов: `r"C:\..."` (`r` - перед кавычками) - тогда не нужно будет экранировать обратные слэши